# Remote execution of Coded UI Tests on a Windows XP VM

Tags: automated-tests, mstest, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests, specflow

I have a Coded UI + SpecFlow test project (.NET Framework 4).

I want to perform remote test execution, so I configured a Visual Test Agent - Controller environment setup. My local machine is the Controller and there is a virtual machine which is the agent. The AUT will run on a Windows Embedded System with Windows XP SP3. The AUT is a WPF application.

VM properties:

- Windows XP SP 3
- Microsoft Test Agent 2012 is installed on the VM ([Agents for Visual Studio 2012 Update 3](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38186))

The agent-controller communication is established successfully (Agent - Online, OK; Controller - Running, OK; TestSettings.testsettings - Configured, OK). The test execution is performed using mstest.

The following error is displayed when I execute the tests:

```
Test Name:  CodedUITestMethod1
Test FullName:  Remote.Test.CodedUITest1.CodedUITestMethod1
Test Source:    c:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Remote.Test\Remote.Test\CodedUITest1.cs : line 27
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:01.7131241

Result Message: Error calling Initialization method for test class Remote.Test.CodedUITest1: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.CrossBrowser, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. Strong name validation failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013141A) ---> System.Security.SecurityException: Strong name validation failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013141A)
Result StackTrace:  
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoadFile(String path, Evidence evidence)
at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(String path)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Framework.UITestExtensionPackageManager.LoadAssembly(String assemblyFile)
```

By definition Coded UI does [not support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380742.aspx) Windows XP.

Is there a workaround for the upper mentioned issue? Any suggestions?

Thank you,

Comment: The "not supported" link shows a Visual Studio 2013 page. The 2012 page has similar support. Check the 2010 page which does support XP. It is possible that some of the 2010 DLLs or the 2010 agent could be put onto the VM to achieve what you want. For the Coded UI part it may be easier to use a VM with a newer version of Windows.

Comment: @AdrianHHH: Thanks for the comment! The solution should be reproducible on the build server (proper dependencies, minimal rework, no hacks), therefore the .dll manipulation/replacement/overwrite is not what I'm looking for. Changing tools neither. Using a VM with a newer Windows is excluded (client) because the AUT will run on Windows XP and I have to use a VM which has similar (close to _exact_) properties as the real end-user embedded machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isolation of `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.CrossBrowser.dll` from `c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\VSTT\11.0\UITestExtensionPackages\` solved the problem. Action was performed on the remote VM.

The tests are up and running.

Comment: Can you clarify what you meant by "isolation" here?  Did you remove that assembly entirely?  Did you remove references to that assembly from the test code? I want to test this exact scenario and could use any pointers you can provide!